# Maximum length of message using Indy components

Tags: delphi, indy, indy-9

I'm trying send message from delphi-code use `TIdMessage`. The message consists of  2 parts: `text/plain` and `text/html`. 
   I have html-page as a template and some large text that need to insert to the template (in special place that was marked as ##text##). After merge the template and the text I get body of my new message. Then I send this message (use `TIdMessage` and `TIdSMTP`), but in a result the message contain only second part of the text. The text have more 40,000 characters. 
When I send message without html-tmplate (only large text) the everything is Ok.

How can I set length of message?

I tried to set `FIdMessage.ContentTransferEncoding := 'quoted-printable' and FIdSMTP.MsgLineLength := MAXWORD;` but it did not help me.

Thanks in advance.
Here are some code:

```
var
  FSMTP: TIdSMTP;
  FIdMessage: TIdMessage;
  idx: integer;
  i: Integer;
  FIdText: TIdText;
begin
  FSMTP := TIdSMTP.Create( nil );
  FIdMessage := TIdMessage.Create( nil );
  try
    try
      FIdMessage.ExtraHeaders.Clear;
      FIdMessage.MessageParts.Clear;

      // Attachments
      for idx := 0 to Attachments.Count - 1 do
        TIdAttachment.Create( FIdMessage.MessageParts,
          TEmailAttachment( Attachments.Items[ idx ] ).FLocalTemplateName );


      FIdMessage.From.Text := FFrom;
      FIdMessage.Recipients.EMailAddresses := FTo;
      FIdMessage.Subject := FSubject;
      if (FHtmlTemplateFilePath <> '') then
      begin
        FIdMessage.ContentType := 'multiparts/related; type="text/html"';
        AddAttachements(FIdMessage);  // procedure that added Attachments

        FIdText := TIdText.Create(FIdMessage.MessageParts, nil);
        FIdText.Body.Text := 'Please view a html version of this email';
        FIdText.ContentType := 'text/plain';


        FIdText := TIdText.Create(FIdMessage.MessageParts, nil);
        FIdText.Body.Text := FBody;
        FIdText.ContentType := 'text/html';

      end
      else
      begin
        FIdMessage.Body.Text := FBody;
      end;    

      FIdMessage.CCList.Clear;
      FIdMessage.ReceiptRecipient.Text := '';

      FSMTP.AuthenticationType := FSMTPAuthenticationType;
      FSMTP.UserID := FSMTPUserID;
      FSMTP.Password := FSMTPPassword;
      FSMTP.Host := FSMTPHost;
      FSMTP.Port := FSMTPPort;
      FSMTP.MsgLineLength := MAXWORD;

      RepeatRetryCount := FSMTPRepeatRetryCount;
      FSMTP.Connect;
       try
            FSMTP.Send( FIdMessage );
       finally
            FSMTP.Disconnect;
       end;
     except
       end;
  finally
    FSMTP.Free;
    FIdMessage.Free;
  end;
end;
procedure AddAttachements(AIdMessage: TidMessage);
var
  LCid: Integer;
  LFileName, LFileExt, LSearchFolder: String;
  LSearchResult: TSearchRec;
  Attachment: TIdAttachment;
begin
  FHtmlCids.Clear;
  LSearchFolder := ExtractFilePath(FHtmlTemplateFilePath)+ChangeFileExt(ExtractFileName(FHtmlTemplateFilePath),'');
  if (FindFirst(LSearchFolder + '_*', faDirectory, LSearchResult)=0) or
     (FindFirst(LSearchFolder + '.*', faDirectory, LSearchResult)=0)
  then
    LSearchFolder := LSearchResult.Name;

  FindClose(LSearchResult);
  if FindFirst(ExtractFilePath(FHtmlTemplateFilePath)+LSearchFolder+'\*.*', faAnyFile - faDirectory, LSearchResult)=0 then
  begin
    repeat
      Attachment := TIdAttachment.Create(AIdMessage.MessageParts, ExtractFilePath(FHtmlTemplateFilePath)+ LSearchFolder + '\' + LSearchResult.Name);
      LCid := Random(MaxInt);
      Attachment.ExtraHeaders.Values['Content-ID'] := IntToStr(LCid);
      LFileName := ExtractFileName(LSearchResult.Name);
      LFileExt := ExtractFileExt(LSearchResult.Name);
      if UpperCase(LFileExt) = '.XML' then
        Attachment.ContentType := 'text/xml'
      else if UpperCase(LFileExt) = '.PNG' then
        Attachment.ContentType := 'image/png'
      else if UpperCase(LFileExt) = '.THMX' then
        Attachment.ContentType := 'application/vnd.ms-officetheme'
      else if UpperCase(LFileExt) = '.JPG' then
        Attachment.ContentType := 'image/jpeg'
      else if UpperCase(LFileExt) = '.GIF' then
        Attachment.ContentType := 'image/gif'
      else if UpperCase(LFileExt) = '.SVG' then
        Attachment.ContentType := 'image/svg+xml'
      else if UpperCase(LFileExt) = '.TIF' then
        Attachment.ContentType := 'image/tiff'
      else if UpperCase(LFileExt) = '.TIFF' then
        Attachment.ContentType := 'image/tiff'
      else if UpperCase(LFileExt) = '.ICO' then
        Attachment.ContentType := 'image/vnd.microsoft.icon'
      else if UpperCase(LFileExt) = '.BMP' then
        Attachment.ContentType := 'image/bmp'
      else if UpperCase(LFileExt) = '.CSS' then
        Attachment.ContentType := 'text/css'
      else if UpperCase(LFileExt) = '.JS' then
        Attachment.ContentType := 'application/javascript'
      else if UpperCase(LFileExt) = '.JPEG' then
        Attachment.ContentType := 'image/jpeg'
      else if UpperCase(LFileExt) = '.WMZ' then
        Attachment.ContentType := 'application/x-ms-wmz'
      else raise Exception.CreateFmt('Unknown file type "%s"', [LFileExt]);
      FHtmlCids.AddObject(LSearchFolder+'/'+LFileName, TObject(LCid));
      FHtmlCids.AddObject(UrlEncode(LSearchFolder+'/'+LFileName), TObject(LCid));
    until FindNext(LSearchResult)<>0;
    FindClose(LSearchResult);
  end;
  FHtmlCids.Sort;
end;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to everybody, I seems found solution.
The problem was with `CR` `LF`. 
Before call my procedure (see above) for send message I inserted large text instead ##text## in html-template. First, I replaced all `CR` `LF` on `<br>` in **my text** and then I replaced ##text## on **my text** in template.
(**my text** - some large text)

As a result I had got body of message before send like:

```
<html>
....
<body>
some large text <br> in one line. This text have more 40,000 characrets.....
</body>
</html>
```

Massage:

> ine. This text have more 40,000 characrets

When I left `CR` `LF` and add tag `<br>`, then I got this body:

```
<html>
....
  <body>
    some large text <br> 
    in one line. This text have more 40,000 characrets.....
  </body>
</html>
```

And message:

> some large text
>   in one line. This text have more 40,000
>   characrets.....

So, in this case if all text is in one line -> massage isn't full, if text in html in a few line -> everything ok

PS. Sorry for my English

Comment: It looks like it's failing if there's no line break (CRLF) every 2048 characters.

Answer (score 2):

`TIdMessage` does not impose a limit on the text length. Something else is going on.  My guess would be that you are simply not filling in the `TIdMessage` correctly. You did not show your `AddAttachments()` code, however you are adding `TIdAttachment` objects before the `TIdText` objects, and that is wrong, especially for the `ContentType` you are using.  I suggest you read the following blog article on Indy's website for the proper structure of an HTML email in `TIdMessage`:

[HTML Messages](http://indyproject.org/Sockets/Blogs/RLebeau/2005_08_17_A.aspx)

However, do take notice of the following warning:

> Unfortunately, Indy 9 does not handle the plaintext+html+images scenerio as well as it should. Indy 10 handles it better...

You are clearly not using Indy 10 (as evident by the fact that you are passing a filename to the `TIdAttachment` constructor - that constructor was moved to a new `TIdAtttachmentFile` class in Indy 10).

Also, just FYI, you do not need to set the `MsgLineLength` property, as it has no effect whatsoever (in fact, I did not know Indy even still had that property - it is a dead property used by `TIdMessageClient.WriteFoldedLine()`, which is itself a dead method that is not used by anything).

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer and your advice. Yes it's Indy 9. I've just added code of AddAttachments().

Comment: I will add TIdAttachment objects after the TIdText objects tomorrow and I will write the result here. Thank you again

Comment: I set TIdAttachment objects after the TIdText objects but the problem left

Comment: I save body `FIdMessage.SaveToFile` before send. The output file contain proper data. So, as I understand the problem with FSMTP?

Comment: No, because `TIdSMTP.Send()` and `TIdMessage.SaveTo...()` use the same generator internally, so the data output is the same (not counting dynamic values, like the `Date` header, and MIME boundaries).

Comment: Thank you! But I don't understand why was the problem with text that is in one line? Is there any limit on length of line in html?